# Can't make inner join with sorting

Tags: hibernate

I have following domain model:

```
class Department {
    Contact primaryContact
    Company company
}
```

When I am executing JPQL query

```
from Department e 
left join e.primaryContact 
where (e.company.id=?) order by e.name asc
```

I get the following SQL:

```
select *aliases* 
     left outer join contact contact1_ 
     on department0_.contact_id=contact1_.ID 
where 
      department0_.company_id=? 
order by department0_.name desc
```

But when I am trying to execute

```
from Department e 
left join e.primaryContact 
where (e.insuranceCompany.id=?) 
order by e.primaryContact.name asc
```

I get:

```
select *aliases* 
  from department department0_ 
       left outer join contact contact1_ on 
       department0_.primary_contact_id = contact1_.ID 
       cross join contact contact2_ 
 where 
         department0_.primary_contact_id = contact2_.ID 
    and department0_.company_id = ? order by contact2_.name desc
```

The difference is

```
cross join contact contact2_ where department0_.primary_contact_id=contact2_.ID
```

So I always have inner join when sorting by `primaryContact.name`

How can I perform left join in this situation? (I am using Hibernate 3.6.10)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

chained expressions always result in an inner join. Assign an alias to the left joined entity, and use the alias:

```
from Department e 
left join e.primaryContact contact
where (e.insuranceCompany.id=?) 
order by contact.name asc
```

Comment: This works perfectly but I cannot understand how to make the order by dynamic (for example when the order by parameter is coming from a user (Swagger)

Comment: By generating the query dynamically. The criteria API, QueryDSL, or just string concatenation (but beware os JPQL injections)